# Make children of imported Three.js group follow pointer when their canvas gets hovered

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, I have a group of meshes that is loaded from outside with help of FBX loader. The group has six meshes inside. My task is to make this meshes follow pointer when they get hovered. More precisely, I'd like to have a sort of magnetic effect (just like navbar items in [this pen](https://codepen.io/ShadiMuma/pen/JxqBbE), but with meshes in Three.js).

I think, firstly, I have to detect, where currently pointer is, i.e. get position of cursor in world coordinates system, and then translate meshes towards it. But when I try to get the position of cursor, it seems to be wrong.

Having said that, I have two questions:

1. How to get proper cursor's position relative to the world coordinates?
2. How to change position of each of the group's meshes so that they get translated against the cursor?

Here is what have I done so far:

Hi everyone.

In Three.js, I have a group of meshes that is loaded from outside with help of FBX loader. The group has six meshes inside. My task is to make this meshes follow pointer when their canvas get hovered. More precisely, I'd like to have a sort of magnetic effect (just like navbar items in [this pen](https://codepen.io/ShadiMuma/pen/JxqBbE), but with meshes of Three.js).

I think, firstly, I have to detect, where currently pointer on canvas is, i.e. get position of cursor in world coordinates system, and then translate meshes towards it. But when I try to get the position of cursor, it seems to be wrong.

Having said that, I have two questions:

1. How to get proper cursor's position relative to the world coordinates?
2. How to change position of each of the group's meshes so that they get translated against the cursor?

Here is what have I done so far. Function that translates meshes isn't written yet. Mousemove callback returns pretty big digits, though:

```
// Load object and play a third-party animation
loader.load("Object_001.fbx", (object) => {
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
const action = mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]);
action.play();

object.traverse((child) => {
  if (child.isMesh) {
    child.material.map = texture;
    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
scene.add(object);
});


// log coordinates of the pointer
const mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
const position = new THREE.Vector3();

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.set(
    (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
    -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
    0.5
  );
  mouse.unproject(camera);
  mouse.sub(camera.position).normalize();
  const distance = -camera.position.z / mouse.z;
  position.copy(camera.position).add(mouse.multiplyScalar(distance));
  console.log(position);
}

wrapperElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Made a codepen here:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/YzxPPZQ

The cursor only exists in the canvas dom element which is a rendering of the camera view frustum.

The easiest way to make the object follow a mouse is to get the point of intersection of the mouse with another object in the 3d scene and set the object position to the intersection point. The above codepen showcases that.

```js
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([ground]);
if(intersects.length) {
    const { point } = intersects[0];
    cube.position.copy(point.setY(0.5));
}
```

You could also position it at a fixed distance from the mouse but it looks odd in my opinion:

```js
const distance = 10;
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
const { origin, direction } = raycaster.ray;
cube.position.copy(origin.clone().add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance)));
```

Documentation for raycaster:
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=ray#api/en/core/Raycaster

> Raycasting is used for mouse picking (working out what objects in the
> 3d space the mouse is over) amongst other things.